# bashrc echo coming in jsch output stream

Tags: java, linux, jsch

I am using the following code to get output of command using JSCH library,

```
    public SSHOutputBean executeCommand(String cmd, int timeOut) {

            SSHOutputBean outputBean=new SSHOutputBean();
            Channel ch=null;
        try {
            ch= this.session.openChannel("exec");

            ChannelExec chExec= ((ChannelExec) ch);
            chExec.setErrStream(System.err);
            chExec.setInputStream(null);
            chExec.setCommand("reset;"+cmd);
            chExec.connect();
            outputBean.setInputStream( chExec.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader brInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputBean.getInputStream()));
            outputBean.setErrorStream(chExec.getErrStream());
            BufferedReader brError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputBean.getErrorStream()));
            while (true) {
                try {

                    String result = brInput.readLine();
                    if (result == null)
                        break;
                    outputBean.getOutput().append(result+"\n");

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                }
            }

            while (true) {
                try {

                    String result = brError.readLine();
                    if (result == null)
                        break;
                    outputBean.getError().append(result+"\n");

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                }
            }

 if (chExec.isClosed()) {

                outputBean.setExitStatus(chExec.getExitStatus());

            }
            chExec.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSchException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(ch!=null)
                ch.disconnect();
        }

    return outputBean;
}
```

The problem is, If bashrc file on the client is printing something on the console, then each time I open a ChannelExec and run a command; the output given on command execution conatins the output of the command as well as the bashrc output. I just want the output of the command and not the bashrc prints.

For example,

If I have put below code in .bashrc file

echo "welcome user"

and If I run a command using jsch,

SSHOutputBean sshOutputBean = ssh.executeCommand("uptime");

then The output is,

**welcome user** (.bashrc output)

**13:15:10 up 2 days,  1:53,  8 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.06, 0.06** (actual command output)

but I want the output to be,

**13:15:10 up 2 days,  1:53,  8 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.06, 0.06** (actual command output)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you cannot simply change the .bashrc to be quiet.  If you are wanting to isolate the output that was a result of your command, and ignore anything before that, an Exec channel may not be your best bet.  When you run the command, your stream coming out is going to include all of the output.

You could try using a shell instead.  You could have it connect and have your stream read all the initial output (ie. the "welcome user" or other output from your .bashrc file).  Then flush the stream, then execute your command and read in the stream, to only see output from the command itself.

Alternatively, you could do a work around with channelExec.  Use channel.setEnv(name, value) to set the PS1 variable to include some delimiting string.  For example:

```
channel.setEnv("PS1","Command Starts Here::")
```

You could then parse your output on your prompt on your delimiting string "Command Starts Here::"

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for such a lucid answer. I have tried using shell also and It prints the .bashrc output once but It also prints 
[username@hostname ]$ command 
with every command.
The workaround is excellent, but I already have in place another in which I echo a string before the execution of command and then use this string as a delimiter. I was looking for some concrete solution in which We can use some JSCH options to do the required.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: the [username@hostname]$ sounds like a prompt.  Those are controlled with PS1, PS2, PS3 and PS4 environment variables.  You can use setEnv to remove the prompt for your channel (with exec or shell).  Echo is a nice simple work around.  I do not think you are going to find something built in to address the issue because of the nature of the promblem--The channel has an output stream, your server is sending output to it.  You can either Quiet it on the server side, or do a parse/filter on the client side.  Maybe Paŭlo Ebermann will chime in with some top secret jsch functionality :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes it seems that there is no other option to echo and then do a parser at the server side.